# How do I redirect to my same URL without getting a too many redirects error?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect users from http://myurl.com/Login.action to http://myurl.com/app/Login.action

I tried this but I get an error saying I get too many redirects.

```
RedirectMatch ([A-Za-z]*)\.action$ http://myurl.com/app/$1.action
```

How can I get apache to redirect to the same URL but only redirect once.

Would something like this work?

```
RedirectMatch ![app\/]([A-Za-z]*)\.action$ http://myurl.com/app/$1.action
```

Answer (score 5):

your regular expression matches both urls, so you're redirecting in an infinite loop.

Try something like this:

```
RedirectMatch ^([^\/]+?\.action)$ http://myurl.com/app/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Rob, thanks for your guidance. I modified yours a bit and this is what I came up with.

```
RedirectMatch ^\/([A-Za-z]+\.action)$ http://myurl.com/app/$1
```